# Select data from 2 tables + propel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, propel

I have a table "parkinggarages" with a foreign key "location_id". I also have a table "locations".

> **Table parkinggarages**:
>   - id
>   - phone
>   - defaultlanguage
>   - capacity
>   - floors
>   - parkingtype
>
> **Table locations:**
>
>   - id
>   - location
>   - lat
>   - lon

Now I want to select all the parkinggarages but I also want to select the "location" field from table "locations" with it.

How can I do this? I've tried this, but didn't work:

```
$result = ParkinggarageQuery::create()->joinWith('Location.location')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$parkinggarages = ParkinggarageQuery::create()
            ->leftJoinWith('Parkinggarage.Location')
            ->find();
```